# Pivot_table for same column names - Must repeat after pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have data as below

```
user  region  attribute   reading
Jon   Europe  fathername  peter
Jon   Europe  age         50
Jon   Europe  mothername  mary
Jon   Europe  age         44
Jon   Europe  brothername duke
Jon   Europe  age         25
```

This is how it is stored in sql database. I am reading this into a dataframe and trying to generate the  data as below

```
attribute             fathername age mothername age brothername age     
User      region
Don       Europe      peter      50   mary      44  duke         25
```

However, I am unable to get this

The age does not repeat and appears only once and takes any one of those values

This is what I have tried -

```
pd.pivot_table(df_mysql , index=['User'],columns=['attribute'],values=['reading'], aggfunc=lambda x: x,dropna = 'False')
```

Repeated attribute(column ) must appear. May I have any ideas on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in pandas is best avoid duplicated columns names, so possible solution is deduplicate repeated values with `pivot`:

```
print (df)
    user  region    attribute reading
0    Jon  Europe   fathername   peter
1    Jon  Europe          age      50
2    Jon  Europe   mothername    mary
3    Jon  Europe          age      44
4    Jon  Europe  brothername    duke
5    Jon  Europe          age      25
6   Jon1  Europe   fathername   peter
7   Jon1  Europe          age      50
8   Jon1  Europe   mothername    mary
9   Jon1  Europe          age      44
10  Jon1  Europe  brothername    duke
11  Jon1  Europe          age      25

m = df.duplicated(['user','region', 'attribute'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'attribute'] += df[m].groupby(['user','region', 'attribute']).cumcount().astype(str)

df = df.pivot_table(index=['user','region'],
                    columns='attribute',
                    values='reading',
                    aggfunc='sum').reindex(df['attribute'].unique(), axis=1)
print (df)
attribute   fathername age0 mothername age1 brothername age2
user region                                                 
Jon  Europe      peter   50       mary   44        duke   25
Jon1 Europe      peter   50       mary   44        duke   25
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I will try this. However, out of curiosity can I not do this in pivot_table()

Comment: @RathiRao - because `pivot_table` is used for aggregation, if not possible use `pivot`

Comment: @RathiRao - better it is explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. I used the pivot_table with lambda. So, I am curious to know if  a lambda can be written to suffice my requirement?

Comment: @RathiRao - Not possible, here lambda not working for your expcted output.

Comment: in your solution can I have multple value for index? User, firstname, lastname and then the rest of the columns

Comment: @RathiRao - Answer is edited for new column - here is used `pivot_table` with `sum`.